# Relocation on assignment when using a std::deque

Tags: c++, stl, deque

Does the C++ standard guarantee that when one pushes back a new element into a deque, none of the pre-existing elements will be relocated to a new memory address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the standard provides such a guarantee:

> ### 23.3.3.4 deque modiﬁers [lib.deque.modiﬁers]
>
> ```
> iterator insert(const_iterator position, const T& x);
>
> iterator insert(const_iterator position, T&& x);
> iterator insert(const_iterator position, size_type n, const T& x);
> template <class InputIterator>
> iterator insert(const_iterator position,
> InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
> iterator insert(const_iterator position, initializer_list<T>);
> template <class... Args> void emplace_front(Args&&... args);
> template <class... Args> void emplace_back(Args&&... args);
> template <class... Args> iterator emplace(const_iterator position, Args&&... args);
> void push_front(const T& x);
> void push_front(T&& x);
> void push_back(const T& x);
> void push_back(T&& x);
> ```
>
> 1. Effects: An insert in the middle of the deque invalidates all the iterators and references to elements of the deque.
>   **An insert at either end of the deque** invalidates all the iterators to the deque, but **has no effect on the validity of references to
>   elements of the deque.**

Absence of effect on references in fact mean that elements will not be relocated.

<sub>According to the C++11 working draft N3242=11-0012</sub>